# Selector1 - Find child - When click Close selector1

Tags: jquery

Im learning to write my code as orginized and clean as possible,
and i got to a part where i cant find the solution searching in google and stackoverflow..

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
$('.selector').find('.close').click(function(){
  ('.selector').hide()
})
```

Is there a way to use selector as `$(this)`?

here is a bigger example function:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page', function (){ /*do stuff*/ })
    .on('click', '.openBulk', function(){
        $('.bulk').show().find('.close')
            .click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            //where $(this) is $('bulk'), is it possible?
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `click` handler `this` will refer to the `.close` element as that's the last selected. To go back up the DOM to find the parent `.bulk`, use `closest()`:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page', function () { 
  /* do stuff */ 
}).on('click', '.openBulk', function() {
  $('.bulk').show().find('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.bulk').hide();
  })
})
```

Also note you're currently duplicating the `.close` click handler every time a `.openBulk` element is clicked. As the `click` handler for `.close` cannot be fired while `.bulk` is hidden, you can make the code clearer by separating the event handlers:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page', function () { 
  /* do stuff */ 
}).on('click', '.openBulk', function() {
  $('.bulk').show();
})

$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.bulk').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` inside your click event refer to the clicked element which has the class `close`, if you want to get the related parent `.bulk` element you could use `.closest()` or `.parents()` :

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page', function (){ 
     /*do stuff*/ 
}).on('click', '.openBulk', function(){
     $('.bulk').show().find('.close').click(function(){
          $(this); //Refer to clicked '.close'

           var parent_bulk = $(this).closest('.bulk');
           //Or also 
           var parent_bulk = $(this).parents('.bulk');
       })
    })
})
```

**NOTE :** You should put the event attachement outside of the other click event, else every time you click another click event will be attached to `.close`.

Also as @Rory noted in the comment `.closest()` and `.parents()` operate slightly differently. `closest()` gets the first matching parent, whereas `parents()` gets all of them, so if your attaching event to div's it's better to use `parents()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `closest()` and `parents()` operate slightly differently. `closest()` gets the first matching parent, whereas `parents()` gets *all* of them. May not be relevant to the OPs use case, but worth remembering